# Project Euler #23 in C#

Tags: c#

Project Euler [challenge 23](https://projecteuler.net/problem=23) states this:

> A perfect number is a number for which the sum of its proper divisors is exactly equal to the number. For example, the sum of the proper divisors of 28 would be 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 = 28, which means that 28 is a perfect number.
>
> A number n is called deficient if the sum of its proper divisors is less than n and it is called abundant if this sum exceeds n.
>
> As 12 is the smallest abundant number, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 = 16, the smallest number that can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers is 24. By mathematical analysis, it can be shown that all integers greater than 28123 can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers. However, this upper limit cannot be reduced any further by analysis even though it is known that the greatest number that cannot be expressed as the sum of two abundant numbers is less than this limit.
>
> **Find the sum of all the positive integers which cannot be written as the sum of two abundant numbers.**

So I've been trying to get this working, however I keep getting back an incorrect result, I'm not sure where this is going wrong in the code though I have:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> abundantNums = Enumerable.Range(12, 1000000).Where(i => isAbundant(i)).ToList();
        abundantNums = abundantNums.Distinct().ToList();
        
        var boolArr = new bool[28124];        

        for (int i = 0; i < abundantNums.Count; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = i; j < abundantNums.Count; ++j)
            {
                var sum = abundantNums[i] + abundantNums[j];
                if (sum < 28124) boolArr[sum] = true;
                else break;
            }
        }
            

        var total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < boolArr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (boolArr[i] == false)
            {
                total += i;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(total);
        Console.ReadKey();           
    }

    static bool isAbundant(int num)
    {
        if (getFactors(num).Sum() > num)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And then to find the factors of a number I have:

```
    static List<int> getFactors(int num)
    {
        List<int> factors = new List<int>();
        Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i=1; i < Math.Sqrt(num) + 1; i++)
        {
            if (num % i == 0)
            {
                factors.Add(i);
                if (num / i != i)
                {
                    factors.Add(num / i);
                }
            }
        }
        watch.Stop();
        factors.Remove(num);
        return factors;
    }
```

Now I've been at this for a day or two and as far as I can tell this should be doing the trick, anyone wiser than I able to point out my failings?

Comment: Please also state the problem statement.

Comment: What result do you get and what did you expect?

Comment: 4178816 is the result I'm getting, I'm not sure what I'm expecting as I do not know the correct answer off hand, I just know that it says that this is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `getFactors` loop. Change:

```
for (int i=1; i < Math.Sqrt(num) + 1; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i=1; i <= Math.Sqrt(num); i++)
```

And it should work. I'll let you try and understand why :-)

Comment: That changed the output however it's still saying my new result is wrong as well

Comment: @Coombes works for me: [check it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SjXM19) ... what result are you expecting? `4179871` should be the correct result